# Disable option selected from 2 dropdowns || toggle options

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, dropdown

i have 2 dropwdowns

when dropdown 1 option is selected it should disable dropdown 2 option so that you cannot select it

here is my code

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="from_account">From Account:</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="from_account" id="selectBox1" onchange="checkvalue1()">
                            <option disabled selected>Transfer From Account</option>
                            @foreach($accounts as $account)
                                <option value="{{$account->id}}">{{$account->account_number}} {{$account->account_name}} R{{$account->current_balance}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="to_account">To Account:</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="to_account" id="selectBox2" onchange="checkvalue2()">
                            <option disabled selected>Transfer To Account</option>
                            @foreach($accounts as $account)
                                <option value="{{$account->id}}">{{$account->account_number}} {{$account->account_name}} R{{$account->current_balance}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

here is my JS

```
      function checkvalue1(){
        $("#selectBox2 option").each(function(){
            if($("#selectBox1 option:selected").val() == $(this).val())
                $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            else
                $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
        });
    }

    function checkvalue2(){
        $("#selectBox1 option").each(function(){
            if($("#selectBox2 option:selected").val() == $(this).val())
                $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            else
                $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
        });
    }
```

i have got it to work in a weird way and it is a bit buggy and i need help please!

let me explain

if i select dropdown 1  it does disable the option in dropdown 2 but it also allows me to select the option that i disabled from the start.

this should be disabled by default and not change[image: Disabled]

and then i need it to kinda like toggle so if i select account 1 for example it should switch between them because now i have to select something else or refresh the page before i can click on another option to choose i hope it makes sense[image: toggle]

Answer (score 0):

in both the functions checkvalue1 & checkvalue2, else condition should be like this:

```
if($(this).val() != ''){
  $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

so final function should be:

```
function checkvalue1(){
        $("#selectBox2 option").each(function(){
            if($("#selectBox1 option:selected").val() == $(this).val())
                $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            else
                if($(this).val() != ''){
                   $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understood correctly so the following  might not be what you tried to describe.

Essentially the 2nd dropdown is initially disabled until the 1st dropdown has a selection made. Once that selection is made the 2nd dropdown is enabled but it makes no sense to transfer money from and to the same account so if the value selected in the 2nd dropdown is the same then we disable the 1st dropdown. This works either way  - basically the `other` dropdown will be disabled...??

I modified the HTML a little by placing the `select` within the `label` and removed the `ID` & `for` attributes for cleaner markup.

```js
let col=document.querySelectorAll('select.form-control');

const changehandler=function(e){
  let other=document.querySelector('select.form-control:not( [ name="'+this.name+'" ] )');
  if(other.disabled==true )other.disabled=false;
  if(this.value==other.value)other.disabled=true;
};

col.forEach(sel=>sel.addEventListener('change',changehandler));
```

```css
label{display:inline-block;padding:0.5rem;margin:1rem;width:50%;}
select{padding:1rem;float:right;width:50%;margin-top:-1rem;}
select[disabled]{border:2px solid red;}
```

```html
<div class='form-group'>
    <label>From Account:
        <select class='form-control' name='from_account'>
            <option disabled selected hidden>Transfer From Account
            <option>abc-12345
            <option>def-89743
            <option>xyz-23423
            <option>pto-42342
            <option>tyk-23427
            <option>mrp-23456
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
<div class='form-group'>
    <label>To Account:
        <select class='form-control' name='to_account' disabled>
            <option disabled selected hidden>Transfer To Account
            <option>abc-12345
            <option>def-89743
            <option>xyz-23423
            <option>pto-42342
            <option>tyk-23427
            <option>mrp-23456
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
```